# Deployment Issue: (MVC4 HotTowel SPA)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, durandal, hottowel

I have developed a web application using VS2012 MVC 4 (HotTowel SPA)
If I run it through Visual Studio it works fine. But when I deploy it to IIS server I am getting an exception.

My server machine is Server 2008 R2 and IIS version 7.5. All the dependencies are installed.

**The code section causing error:**

On index.cshtml page If check `if(Session["User"] == null)` then load view Login. (Login.cshtml)
If session is not null then load the home view.
Everything is working fine if running through visual studio.
If I remove the Session check then home page is loaded successfully.
But I must check the session before going to home. But I get the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

`Line 65:

Line 66:     @if (Session["User"] == null)
Line 67:     {
Line 68:          @Html.Partial("Login")`
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem 
Just add this module to your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
...
<system.webServer>
...
<modules>
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
...
</modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It is very strange that Microsoft did add this module in Template.